# Do the line breaking algorithms of TeX have a penalty for a QED symbol on a single line?

Tags: line-breaking, amsthm

The question is about the qed symbol in an `amsthm`. For example with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfas
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image]

I don't like this at all, because if the text continues after the proof, there will be a lot of blank space which disrupts the flow of the text in my opinion (even more than if a paragraph ends with a single word on the last line, which is also frowned upon in typography, as far as I know). So I wonder if TeX tries to avoid this situation at all and if there is a penalty that I could increase.

Comment: increasing the penalty will only have an effect if there is an alternative break with a lower penalty which seems unlikely in your example. You would have to stretch the inter-word space making things infinitely bad in order to bring some text on to the next line.

Comment: You can add `\linebreak` in front of the last word. In this particular case, I get no “underfull `\hbox`” message. The best is to edit the text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

amsthm defines `\qed` by

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
```

so it already assigns the largest possible penalty short of 10000 (which is the maximum) that means that in your example there is no feasible breakpoint with penalty less than this.

Comment: This answers my question :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few strategies, but the main one is to edit the offending paragraph.

Strategy 1: `\linebreak`

Strategy 2: `\looseness=1`

Here strategy 2 comes into two variants, the latter with `\mbox` to avoid hyphenation.

I'm afraid that making this automatic would be very complicated and fragile, but you could try and add `\looseness=1` to the definition of `\qed`, which might work in several cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfa.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
\linebreak asdfa.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdfa.\looseness=1
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
\mbox{asdfa}.\looseness=1
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]